# iOS delete row from tableView remotely using http post/get

Tags: php, ios, objective-c, uitableview

I can show data in a tableView that is coming from an external DB through a jSON file, but the problem that I have is that I don't know how to delete data from database using objective-c, the PHP file of deletion is ready and working and it is on this format :

> ```
>  http://example.com/delete_info.php?user_id=2&info=someInfo
> ```

### The question :

How can I execute the above URL inside the code ?

As I believe, something should be inserted here, so I can execute the URL :

> ```
>    - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:          (UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
>  {
>   if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {        
>     // Delete the row from the data source
>     [self.destinations_history removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];        
>   }
>   else if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleInsert) {        
>     NSLog(@"create");
>     // Create a new instance of the appropriate class, insert it into the array, and add a new row to the table view
>    }    
> [self.tableView reloadData];
> }
> ```

Comment: I know how to make NSURLCONNECTION, but I don't know where exactly to insert it in tableView, so I execute the URL.

Comment: I would say you can make de delete url request just before [self.destinations_history removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row].

Answer (score 1):

A possible solution:

```
1. In `commitEditingStyle` delegate don't remove the record from your datasource.

2. Instead keep the `indexPath.row` and `indexPath.section` and `hit the url`.

   if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) { 

        // Hit url here
   }

3. In service response callback, once it is successful, use the data gathered 
   in step 2 and eliminate it from tableView datasource.

4. Reload tableView data.
```

hope it helps!